# How can I get the distance in sklearn.neighbors function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, similarity, nearest-neighbor

I have some pictures to recognize, one of them is correct. I try to compare them with my correct dataset by scikit-learn knn function.

I think the distance between correct picture and correct dataset should be nearest.

I can get the correct picture by compare the distance of each picture I need to recognize.

My question is how I can get the distance by scikit-learn knn.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#neighborhood-components-analysis This link might help you.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are simply looking for [`sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html#sklearn-neighbors-distancemetric):

> This class provides a uniform interface to fast distance metric functions.

Apart from that, look at [SSIM (Structural Similarity Index Measure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity) as a method for measuring similarity between images.